# How to temporarily cancel sending of video track in webRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I have created webRtc connection (javascript) and I want to temporarily cancel sending of video track (audio track must remain) to minimize network traffic.
Which actions should I perform to do this:
(1) do `videoTrack.enabled = false;` (videoTrack is MediaStreamTrack)
and then do:`videoTrack.enabled = true;` to restore it
or (2) call videoTrack.stop() ?
What is the differense between (1) and (2) - which case will minimize network traffic ?
How should I restore video sending in the case (2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting .enabled to false will send black frames instead of the actual video which reduces bandwidth usage considerably. Try it on
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/
by pasting `localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false`
which shows around 12kbps plus overhead for headers.

It will still send packets for every frame which may be undesirable in some cases. Using RTCRtpSender's `replaceTrack(null)` or stopping the track reduces that even further.

Stopping the track has the additional advantage that it will turn off the camera light which is what users expect privacy-wise but you will need to call replaceTrack again after re-aquiring video with another call to `getUserMedia`.